# Missing rows in a continuous aggregate timescaledb table

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, candlesticks, continuous-aggregates

I have a tick table in timescaledb as follows from which I create a materialized view for 1-minute OHLC bars with its corresponding refresh policy. However, my `tick_1min` table does not end up having the correct OHLC bar and there are missing bars in the table, as can be seen in below.

```
CREATE TABLE tick
(
    tstamp         TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    tstamp_micro   INT                      NOT NULL,
    exchange       VARCHAR(100)             NOT NULL,
    symbol         VARCHAR(100)             NOT NULL,
    price          DOUBLE PRECISION         NOT NULL,
    vwap           DOUBLE PRECISION         NOT NULL,
    size           INT                      NOT NULL,
    volume_bought  INT                      NOT NULL,
    volume_sold    INT                      NOT NULL,
    side           SMALLINT                 NOT NULL,
    context        VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL
);
SELECT create_hypertable('tick', 'tstamp');
```

**materialized view for 1-minute OHLC bars**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tick_1min
    WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT time_bucket('1 minute', tstamp) AS bucket,
       symbol,
       first(tick.price, tick."tstamp")  AS open,
       max(tick.price)                   AS high,
       min(tick.price)                   AS low,
       last(tick.price, tick."tstamp")   AS close
FROM tick
GROUP BY symbol, bucket;

-- Refresh policy
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('tick_1min',
                                       start_offset => INTERVAL '1 day', --
                                       end_offset => INTERVAL '1 minute',
                                       schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 minute');

-- Manual refresh
CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('tick_1min', now() - interval '1 week', now())
```

**Missing rows in `tick_1min`**, e.g., data from 22:25:00 to 22:28:00 is not added.

```
2024-02-21 22:23:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:24:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.0  5008.25 5008.0  5008.25
2024-02-21 22:29:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.0  5008.0  5008.0  5008.0
2024-02-21 22:31:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:32:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:34:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.0  5008.0  5008.0  5008.0
2024-02-21 22:38:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:41:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:44:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.0  5008.25 5008.0  5008.25
2024-02-21 22:45:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.25 5008.25 5008.25 5008.25
2024-02-21 22:49:00.000 -0800   MESH4   5008.0  5008.0  5008.0  5008.0
```

I am expecting that even if the tick data is missing for that period, it still produces a new bar with Open=High=Low=Closed=Previous closed.

Could someone kindly let me know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the timescaledb extension version? Can you share some snippet of the inserts to confirm what you're expecting?

Comment: I already have examples of the missing rows issue in my post. I am using TimescaleDB version: 2.10.2 and PostgreSQL version: 14.7.

Comment: Continuous aggregates will not fill information with pre-processing projections because it may be backfilled later.

Use a regular query over the continuous aggregates using  `time_bucket_gapfill` function and then you can combine with `locf` and create a new candlestick from last close. 

You can make it a view to access it in a easy way but materializing will not be possible.